# Show that a polynomial $f(x)$ over a field $k$ is irreducible if and only if the polynomial $f(x+1)$ is irreducible

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I have literally no idea how to do this. I tried writing out $f(x+1)$ and rewriting it but didn't seem to get anywhere. I suspect I should use the degree of the polynomials but don't know how.

Answer (score 6):

Let me phrase this in a somewhat more general context.

Let $R$ be a UFD. Then, for any $\alpha\in R$ which is irreducible, $\varphi(\alpha)$ is irreducible for every $\varphi\in\text{Aut}(R)$. Indeed, if $\varphi(\alpha)=\beta\gamma$, where neither $\beta$ nor $\gamma$ are units, then certainly $\alpha=\varphi^{-1}(\beta)\varphi^{-1}(\gamma)$, and since $\delta$ is a unit if and only if $\varphi(\delta)$ is a unit, we arrive at a contradiction.

You're problem then just comes from the fact that $f(x)\mapsto f(x+1)$ is a ring automorphism of $k[x]$.

Comment: sorry, how could you write $\alpha=\phi^{-1}(\beta)\phi^{-1}(\gamma)$, if $R$ is a polynomial ring? Are you inverting polynomial?

Answer (score 4):

Hint : $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ if and only if $f(x+1)=g(x+1)h(x+1)$.